# Prior and Posterior Domain

Tags: bayesian

Essentially the posterior distribution $p(\theta|x)$ and the prior distribution $p(\theta)$ are defined on the same domain $\Theta$, it is just the allocate their mass differently?

Comment: No the likelihood can as well restrict the support of $\theta$.

Comment: @Xi'an While that might make the posterior probability or density $0$ on part of the original support (i.e. shrink the support), I am not sure that counts as a different domain

Comment: @Henry that what I was also thinking

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say that you are estimating binomial proportion and you have prior knowledge that it is certainly higher than 0.5 but you have no other knowledge on its value. In such a case, you could use a uniform prior between 0.5 and 1. Multiplying likelihood by it would restrict the posterior probabilities to be non-zero only for the range as restricted by the prior. So technically the binomial proportion could range over the whole unit interval, but the choice of prior restricted the posterior. Posterior, by definition, would be non-zero everywhere where prior times likelihood is non-zero.

Comment: So essentially it can be considered as the domain of the prior with zero density on thetas that are zero dye to likelihood